# Removing line from array

Tags: arrays, lua, coronasdk, lua-table

I have a question in Lua (Corona SDK):

I have a whiteboard that can draw and clear, but I am having problems with my clear. This is the drawing function I have:

```
if(phase == 'moved') then
    local xStart, yStart = self.xStartTemp or e.xStart, self.yStartTemp or e.yStart

    --add new line
    local xEnd, yEnd = e.x, e.y
    local line = display.newLine(xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd)

    -- self:drawCircleStream(e.x, e.y)

    self.xStartTemp, self.yStartTemp = xEnd, yEnd
    line.strokeWidth = 1
    line:setStrokeColor(0,0,0)
    self.group:insert(line)
    self.line = line
elseif(phase == 'ended') then
    --store line in a table
    self.xStartTemp, self.yStartTemp = nil, nil
    local lineArr = self.lineArr
    table.insert(lineArr, self.line)
end
return true
```

And this is the clear (which doesn't work):

```
local lineArr = self.lineArr
for i=1,#lineArr do
    print(lineArr[i])
    table.remove(lineArr[i])
    -- lineArr[i]:removeSelf()
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The function [`table.remove`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-table.remove) accepts two arguments: The table itself and the index from where value is to be removed.

There, the code should actually be:

```
for i = 1, #lineArr do
    print( lineArr[i] )
    table.remove( lineArr, i )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can also try a simple way if you are aware of which value to remove:

```
for k, v in pairs (tableName) do
    if v==YOUR-VALUE then
        tableName[k] = nil
        return
    end
end
```

Just simply change the "YOUR-VALUE" and add the value (if you are aware of it).

Comment: The code in the question assumes the table is a [sequence](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.6). Your code can  make the table not a sequence, thereby making the result of `#` undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In your clear function. `table.remove` shifts your table elements down to fill the gap when you remove, and when that's combined with iterating in a for-loop, it will give you unexpected behavior:

```
 t  =  { 2, 4, 6 }
 for i, _ in ipairs(t) do
    table.remove(t, i)
 end
 for _, v in ipairs(t) do
   print(v)
 end
```

The end result will be, `t` still has the value 4.

If you want to empty a  table, just assign a fresh one:

```
 self.lineArr = {}
```

To clear an array without creating a new table, do:

```
  for i=1,#array do array[i] = nil end
```